# Apache Error AH02430: Response header 'Location' value of contains invalid characters, aborting request

Tags: apache, servlets

## Issue

I have a JBoss Servlet Application (WildFly Server) running with TeamSite Apache v2.4.56. Once I submit a form to App Server, the browser return 500 Internal Server Error

The WildFly server.log doesn't contain any error log, but Apache modsec_audit.log and ssl_error.log contain error logs that seems related:

modsec_audit.log

```
Apache-Error: [file "E:\\jenkins\\workspace\\thirdparty-httpd\\label_exp\\nti64\\src\\httpd-2.4.56\\modules\\http\\http_filters.c"] [line 728] [level 3] AH02430: Response header 'Location' value of 'https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist_text=Eastern - q@&act_text=Tennis - \\xb2\\x03&msg=Updated Successfully!&master_ind=1&dist=loc1&act=062' contains invalid characters, aborting request

Apache-Error: [file "E:\\jenkins\\workspace\\thirdparty-httpd\\label_exp\\nti64\\src\\httpd-2.4.56\\modules\\http\\http_filters.c"] [line 728] [level 3] AH02430: Response header 'Location' value of 'https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist_text=Eastern - q@&act_text=Table-Tennis - RS\\x03&msg=Updated Successfully!&master_ind=1&dist=loc1&act=060' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

ssl_error.log

```
[Thu Feb 01 17:30:20.645592 2024] [http:error] [pid 4232:tid 1640] [client 10.40.20.40:2060] AH02430: Response header 'Location' value of 'https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist_text=Wanchai - c\xd4&act_text=Tennis - \xb2\x03&msg=Updated Successfully!&master_ind=1&dist=loc2&act=062' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist=loc2&act=062&dist_text=Wanchai+-+%E7%81%A3%E4%BB%94&act_text=Tennis+-+%E7%B6%B2%E7%90%83&master_ind=1

[Thu Feb 01 17:28:06.596757 2024] [http:error] [pid 4232:tid 1636] [client 10.40.20.40:21607] AH02430: Response header 'Location' value of 'https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist_text=Wanchai - c\xd4&act_text=Table-Tennis - RS\x03&msg=Updated Successfully!&master_ind=1&dist=loc2&act=060' contains invalid characters, aborting request, referer: https://example/iw-webadmin/en/DagcStaging.do?dist=loc2&act=060&dist_text=Wanchai+-+%E7%81%A3%E4%BB%94&act_text=Table-Tennis+-+%E4%B9%92%E4%B9%93%E7%90%83&master_ind=1
```

After trying different cases, I found that this error is occurred due to the App Server include invalid Chinese Character "球"(U+7403) in response header, specifically, every Chinese Character with suffix "03" in Unicode can trigger this error, since I also tried "吃"(U+5403) and able to trigger this error.

So I googled this issue, and tried some approaches, such as:

- set `HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe` in iwebd.conf
- set `SecRuleEngine Off` in modsecurity.conf
- set `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in iwebd.conf

But the problem is still exist.

I have other two work-around approaches.

- This error seems related to [Apache HTTP Request Parsing Whitespace Defects (CVE-2016-8743)](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/apache-httpd-cve-2016-8743/), so I wonder using previous Apache version will escape this issue.
- Second approach is removing the Chinese character from source code, but this need large workload.

I would appreciated for any better approach. And I am happy to provide more information about this issue.

Comment: I solved this problem by encoding the URL parameters in redirect link by URL encoder.